# How to compare two versions of same file (old and new), and detect if there were some changes?

Tags: python

I am new at both, python and stackoverflow, so please have that on mind. I tried to do this myself and manage to do it, but it works only if i hardcode hash number of previous version like this one in hash1, and then compare with hash number of currently version. I wolud like that program every time save hash number of currently version and then with every run compare it with newer version, and if the file is changed do something.

This is my code

```
import hashlib

hash1 = '3379b3b9b9c82650831db2aba0cf4e99'

hasher = hashlib.md5()
    with open('word.txt', 'rb') as afile:
    buf = afile.read()
    hasher.update(buf)
    hash2 = hasher.hexdigest()

if hash1 == hash2:
    print('same version')
else
    print('diffrent version')
```

Comment: You could write out the current hash to a file and then read that file on start.

Comment: Way to long IHMO to post here; but here's a [simplevcs.py](https://gist.github.com/prologic/aa6e46a096e8a0c835d5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply save the hash to a file like file.txt and then when you need to compare a hash just read from your file.txt and compare the two strings. 
Here is an example of how to read and write to files in python. 
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Answer (score 1):

For relatively simple comparisons, use [filecmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html).  For finer control and feedback, use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#module-difflib), which is similar to the *nix utility, `diff`.